Minimizing a function involving a gamma function
In one of the proofs about some estimates of upper bounds of zeros of the Riemann zeta function I am studying, I have a function that looks like
$V(\alpha, x, \delta,T)= \alpha e^{2\alpha(\frac{1}{T} + \frac{\delta}{T\log T})^{x}} \Bigg\{\frac{2C_{1}(\delta)}{\alpha} + 4C_{2}(2\alpha)^{-\frac{x +1}{x}}\Gamma(\frac{x +1}{x})\Bigg\}$.
We are fixing $\alpha$ and $T$; $\delta$ is in $(0,1)$, and I already know that both $C_{1}(\delta)$ and $C_{2}(\delta)$ decreases in $0 < \delta < 1$ (I know the functions explicitly and their behavior with $\delta$ ). We can even fix $\delta$ for our sake.
What I am trying to find is $x$ in terms of $\alpha$ (or also $\delta$ will occur there?), when $V$ is minimized. Simply speaking, this just involves differentiating $V$ and setting it to zero and solving for $x$, and obviously I will be using some computational tool, program to do that.
I have tried in Maple; it is giving me the derivative but fails to solve it, it seems. My question is, what can be a good programming language to do this? Or, maybe, do I need to do some more simplification of $V$ before doing the programming?
Any suggestions/pointers will be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Is the Mathematica result $$\frac{\partial V(\alpha,x,\delta,T)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{x^2} 4 \alpha C_2(2 \alpha)^{-\frac{x+1}{x}} e^{2 \alpha \left(\frac{\delta+\log(T)}{T \log(T)}\right)^x}\ \left(x \log\left(\frac{\delta+\log(T)}{T \log(T)}\right) \left(\frac{\delta+\log(T)}{T \log(T)}\right)^x \left(x C_1(\delta) C_2(2 \alpha)^{\frac{1}{x}+1}+2 \alpha \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)+\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(\log(C_2(2 \alpha))-H_{\frac{1}{x}}+\gamma\right)\right)$$ consistent with your Maple result for the derivative?

@StevenClark, yes, more or less I got this, but when I am trying to solve this to zero, Maple gives an error. It seems, Mathematica can help?

I'm not sure, but what are your definitions of $C_1(\delta)$ and $C_2(\delta)$? What are the constraints on $\alpha$ and $T$?

@StevenClark, you can assume $0 < \alpha < 1$ fixed, and $T$ being a large constant $\geq 10^{9}$,
$C_{1}(\delta) = \frac{1.093}{\delta} (1 + 0.0828\delta)^{2} e^{0.0478\delta}$ and $C_{2}(\delta) = \frac{0.1058}{\delta} (1 + 0.0414\delta)^{2} + 0.00104e^{-2\delta}$.

@StevenClark, I made a typing mistake in $C_{2}(\delta)$ above. The correct $C_{2}(\delta)$ is
$C_{2}(\delta) = \frac{0.1058}{\delta e^{\delta}} (1 + 0.0414\delta)^{2} + 0.00104e^{-2\delta}$.
